# What time does it signify?

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I created a table with one attribute `tt` and inserted a value into it.

```
CREATE TABLE tt(tm TIME);
INSERT INTO tt VALUES(2342342);
```

On executing the `select` command the result shown is in the form :

```
234:23:42
```

What time does this signify ?

Comment: Are you considering your value to be a timestamp ?

Comment: @Nico No,was just testing something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL retrieves and displays `TIME` values in `HH:MM:SS` format or `HHH:MM:SS` format for large hour values.  The reason why it can have large values is because it can also represent an **interval** between two events (which may span over multiple days for example, or even be negative).

H stands for hour, M for minute, and S for second.

So, when you insert `2342342` it becomes `234:23:42` representing 234 hours, 23 minutes, and 42 seconds.

[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html)

Comment: 234 hours in that case. It can span over multiple days.

Answer (score 3):

> MySQL retrieves and displays TIME values in 'HH:MM:SS' format (or
>   'HHH:MM:SS' format for large hours values). TIME values may range from
>   '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'. The hours part may be so large because
>   the TIME type can be used not only to represent a time of day (which
>   must be less than 24 hours), but also elapsed time or a time interval
>   between two events (which may be much greater than 24 hours, or even
>   negative).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html

**MySQL recognizes TIME values in these formats:**

> As a string in 'D HH:MM:SS' format. You can also use one of the
>   following “relaxed” syntaxes: 'HH:MM:SS', 'HH:MM', 'D HH:MM', 'D HH',
>   or 'SS'. Here D represents days and can have a value from 0 to 34.
>
> As a string with no delimiters in 'HHMMSS' format, provided that it
>   makes sense as a time. For example, '101112' is understood as
>   '10:11:12', but '109712' is illegal (it has a nonsensical minute part)
>   and becomes '00:00:00'.
>
> As a number in HHMMSS format, provided that it makes sense as a time.
>   For example, 101112 is understood as '10:11:12'. The following
>   alternative formats are also understood: SS, MMSS, or HHMMSS.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html